# ASP.NET Core 1.0 Identity 3 & BaseEntity

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to extend identity 3 in order to user primary keys as integers and my custom tables. 
The problem is that I want all my database classes to derive from my `BaseEntity` class but the `ApplicationUser` entity is forced to derive from `IdentityUser<int>`.

I need the `BaseEntity` in order to implement my generic repository patterns and `DbContext`.

This is actually what I would like to do, but C# does not support multiple class inheritance:

```
public class User : BaseEntity, IdentityUser<int>
{

}


public abstract  class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }

   //Some extra logic

}
```

Do you have any idea on this one ?

Could I probably implement it with an interface that will wrap somehow `IdentityUser<int>`?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can do that, as the base of Identity Framework is **not** tied to `IdentityUser<T>` type. `Identity<T>` is only used in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` package.

As you can see in the GitHub repository of [Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/3.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework), the `IdentityUser<T>` is only implemented there. You could basically fork it and implement your base class there and use that as your class.

Otherwise you have to implement all of the stores yourself to use your new base class. The base of [Microsoft.AspNet.Identity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/3.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity) do not depend on such a class, all of the generic classes have the `where TUser : class`, which means it can be used with any class.

One easier solution if you don't want to implement your own Implementation based on Identity, is to use an interface:

Then your `User` class will look like this

```
public class IBaseEntity 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : IdentityUser<int>, IBaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```